# create a class object as variable in Tcloo

Tags: oop, tcl

I start to use tclOO.
I need to create a *Aclass* instance **anotherClassIns**  in my main class **MainClass** as below:

```
oo:class create Aclass {
    variable num;
    constructor {argv} {
       set num [lindex $argv 0]
    }
}; #end of Aclass


oo:class create MainClass {
    variable anotherClassIns ; # this variable is another class's instance!
     
    constructor {argv} {
       Aclass create anotherClassIns {$argv};
    } 
}
```

And in main function, I create a MainClass instance:

```
MainClass create Ins $argv
```

If I want to print $num in Aclass, how can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: You're not setting up the owning instance correctly; either it is (possibly locally) named, when you make it with `create`, or it is a generated name (made with `new`) and you store that in a variable. There are advantages to both. _Both_ those methods return the fully-qualified name of the newly created object (unless a metaclass overrides that for some reason; that's only common for classes pretending to be Tk widgets).

Answer (score 1):

All instance variables in TclOO have globally-addressable names so that they can be used with other parts of Tcl that expect such (especially `vwait` and `trace`, but also Tk's `-textvariable` options).

The easiest way for now is to make an accessor method:

```
oo:class create Aclass {
    variable num
    constructor {argv} {
        set num [lindex $argv 0]
    }
    method num {} {
        return $num
    }
}
oo:class create MainClass {
    variable anotherClassIns
     
    constructor {argv} {
        set anotherClassIns [Aclass new {*}$argv]
    }
    destructor {} {
        # Assuming you're owning the inner instance
        $anotherClassIns destroy
    }

    method printTheValue {} {
        puts [$anotherClassIns num]
    }
}
```

You can also access the variable directly by using the fact that variables exist in a namespace, and that namespace can be looked up with `info object namespace`:

```
    method printTheValue {} {
        # Probably easiest to do this
        namespace upvar [info object namespace $anotherClassIns] num v
        puts $v
    }
```

But that won't work with 8.7's private variables, as those are name-mangled in a way that is decidedly non-accessible to outside code. In that case, you'd need to get `Aclass` to provide access into its internals; that's literally the point of private variables. The `varname` method of `oo::object` can help there; it's not exposed by default, but it's available internally via `my`, and you can expose it for a class or even just an instance via the `export` definition.

```
# Probably at object creation time
oo::objdefine $anotherClassIns export varname

# Then, to access
puts [set [$anotherClassIns varname num]]
# Or
upvar 0 [$anotherClassIns varname num] v
puts $v
```

There's a similar `variable` method, but that requires that you don't have a colliding local `num` variable:

```
# Object creation time
oo::objdefine $anotherClassIns export variable

# Access
$anotherClassIns variable num
puts $num
```

Comment: Note that later examples above leave out quite a bit of the boilerplate; it's uninteresting and exactly the same in all cases.

Comment: If you're expanding argv when creating a new instance `Aclass new {*}$argv` then the Aclass constructor should use `args` not `argv`